# Close a DIV Tag and open a new DIV TAG using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have a HTML file with multiple div tags, I want them to break up automatically using JQuery

```
<div class="m1">
   <div>t1</div>
   <div>t2</div>
   <div>t3</div>
</div>
```

I should get the output in below format

```
<div class="m1">
  <div>t1</div>
  <div>t2</div>
  <p>M1 Tag closed</p>
</div>

<div class="m2">
  <div>t3</div>
</div>
```

Please help me guys, tried with all possibilities like insertbefore,insertafter, parent(), append() etc. Appreciate your help.

Comment: what happens if theres a `t4`, `t5`, etc?

Comment: Should this work just for this specific example or is there some generic logic behind this?

Comment: For me it looks like you move one child from an existing parent into a new parent, and then add a new child into the existing one, right? With that in mind you might find/see how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to create a new div, `.m2`, then append the existing final child `div` in to that, while appending a new `p` element to `.m1`. If you break it down in to those steps, it will look something like this:

```js
var $m2 = $('<div class="m2"></div>').appendTo('body');
$('.m1 div:last').appendTo($m2);
$('.m1').append('<p>M1 Tag closed</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1">
   <div>t1</div>
   <div>t2</div>
   <div>t3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help